# Prove that: $\csc 50° + \cot 100° = \cot 25° -\csc 100°$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that: $$\csc 50° + \cot 100° = \cot 25° -\csc 100°$$

My Attempt:

$$L.H.S=\csc 50° + \cot 100°=\frac {1}{\sin 50°} + \frac {\cos 100°}{\sin 100°}$$
$$=\frac {1}{\sin 50°} + \frac {\cos 100°}{2\sin 50°\cos 50°}$$
$$=\frac {2\cos 50° + \cos 100°}{2\sin 50°\cos 50°}$$.

Now, what should I do?

Comment: i think your statement is wrong, have you try it with a calculator?

Comment: Simple consequence of the doubling formulas $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1$ and $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$, hence for every $a$ such that one does not divide by $0$, $$S=\frac{1}{\sin 2a}+\frac{\cos 4a}{\sin 4a}+\frac{1}{\sin 4a}=\frac{1}{\sin 2a}+\frac{1+\cos 4a}{\sin 4a}$$ is also $$S=\frac{1}{\sin 2a}+\frac{2\cos^2 2a}{2\sin 2a\cos 2a}=\frac{1}{\sin 2a}+\frac{\cos 2a}{\sin 2a}=\frac{1+\cos 2a}{\sin 2a}$$ which is also $$S=\frac{2\cos^2a}{2\sin a\cos a}=\frac{\cos a}{\sin a}$$ Now, use this for $$a=25°$$

Comment: yes it is true, it was a typo of mine, thank you

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner "Typo", meaning that you mistyped when you entered the formula into your CAS, yes we know (and nobody is interested, as you have repeatedly been told).

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, with using a calculator I got both R.H.S=L.HS.=1.129080309.

Comment: yes it is true as Did has proved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$\csc2x+\cot2x=\dfrac{1+\cos2x}{\sin2x}=\dfrac{2\cos^2x}{2\cos x\sin x}=\cot x$

Set $x=50^\circ,100^\circ$

Comment: @  lab bhattacharjee,  I request you, please once have a look at this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106883/graph-third-quartle/2106959#2106959. The answer I got here doesn't match with the one provided in my book. The boys says that the answers are $20-30$ and $30$.

Comment: @NeWtoN, Not sure if I have understood u correctly.

Comment: Hello sir, did you see the question. @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 3):

This would work better may be :
   $$\csc 50° + \cot 100° = \cot 25° -\csc 100°$$
   $$\csc 50° + \cot 100° +\csc 100° = \cot 25° $$
   $$\frac{1}{\sin 50°} + \frac{\cos 100°}{\sin 100°} +\frac{1}{\sin 100°} = \cot 25° $$
$$\frac{1}{\sin 50°} + \frac{\cos 100° + 1}{\sin 100°} = \cot 25° $$
$$\frac{1}{\sin 50°} + \frac{2\cos^2 50° }{2\sin 50°\cos 50°} = \cot 25° $$
$$\frac{1}{\sin 50°} + \frac{\cos 50° }{\sin 50°} = \cot 25° $$
$$\frac{1+\cos 50° }{\sin 50°} = \cot 25° $$
$$\frac{2\cos^2 25° }{2\sin 25°\cos 25°} = \cot 25° $$

Done right?

Comment: Hello win vineeeth,  sir.  very wonderful solution.  Do I get your email address or any thing else so that I can contact you out of MSE as well?

Comment: @user354073 I would prefer not. You can use MSE itself to ask me anything. I also want to mention that I am not as good as some of the people here on MSE. Anyway, Glad you liked my solution. Upvote and accept it if worth. Thanks.

Comment: But I have some queries that I want to ask you personally, and get some help.?