# Graph-Third Quartle

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

Find the third quartile class and frequency of the class from the given graph. How many students are there above the class? [image]
My attempt :
Here, $N=120$.
Third quartile lies in $\frac {3N}{4}$item.
$$=90 item$$
So, $Q_3 class = 20-30$.

but I couldn't do that second part of the question. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I would say that the corresponding x-value to the y-value of $90$ is $25$. And the corresponding x-value to the y-value of $60$ is 10. Therefore $Q_3$ class goes from $10$ to $25$.

Comment: @callculus, why do you take $60$ on the y axis.

Comment: @NeWtoN I feel $20$ should be the answer but I have no idea why the book says $30$. If I get the answer with steps, I will post it.

Comment: Ok.  But,  @ Rohan for the last question,  I have an idea that Upper quartile is $25%$ in the more than ogive curve which yields 30. Am I correct Here?

Answer (score 0):

Here,  You have got the $Q_3$ class as $(20-30)$.

Upper limit of the class touches the less than curve at $100$

Lower limit of the class touches the less than curve at $80$. So, frequency of the class $=100-80=20$.

Also,
Corresponding frequency of upper limit of the third quartile class in the more than curve is $20$. So, the number of students above the class is $20$.

.....))