# Question on graph and statistics

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

Find the third quartile class and frequency of the class from the given graph. How many students are there above the class? [image]
My attempt :
Here, $N=120$.
Third quartile lies in $\frac {3N}{4}$item.
$$=90 item$$
So, $Q_3 class = 20-30$.

I have previously asked this question at [Graph-Third Quartle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106883/graph-third-quartle/2106959#2106959)

But the actual answer given in my book is $30$ and the answer given by occasional user there is $20$. How is this difference?  Which one is correct?

Comment: It seems like they're looking for the range of frequency rather than class, as that's about 30, and 20 if people forget to normalize to N=120.

Comment: @Vedvart1, I could clearly see three different questions here

Comment: 1. Find the third quartile class.

Comment: 2.Frequency of the third quartile class and

Comment: 3. How many students are above the class?  I could not get the answer for 2nd and 3rd question.

Comment: Well 2nd and 3rd follow from the first. 2 is just the y-value for whatever x-value you got for 1, and 3 is 25% by the definition of the 3rd Quartile class.

Comment: My best guess about why they have 1 as 30 is rounding up, it does look like it should be 25 or 26...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52646/discussion-between-newton-and-vedvart1).

Comment: @Vedvart,  for 1 it hasn't asked the exact value of third quartile but the class which is $20-30$

Comment: The answer $30$ in the book is not for 1 BUT for the rest questions

Comment: We have different methods to find quartile. You can see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile

Comment: Have you given frequency table in question also. Or only diagram?

Comment: @@Kanwaljit Singh, Only the duagram.

Answer (score 1):

Upper quartile = $\frac{3N}{4}$

N = 120.

Upper quartile = 90th term

Through 90 on the y-axis draw a line parallel to y-axis meeting the curve at P.

From M draw a perpendicular on x-axis which meets it at Q.

You get value 25 on x-axis.

And class is 20-30.

Comment: @@Kanwaljit, and How many students are above the class?  What is the answer for this

Comment: Draw graph and see its 25.

Comment: How's that? please explain--@@kanwaljit

Comment: Read my answer and draw diagram.